# Make return must pass through certain function

Tags: php

I have a class having several methods. I want to restrict the code in such a way that when ever there is any method do `return` it must be done through `sendResponse()` method. No direct return should be allowed.

Is there any pattern or trick to achieve this ?

Thanks

```
class Foo {

function a(){
 ...
 $response = ...;
 return $this->sendResponse($response);
}

function b(){
 ...
 $response = ...;
 return $this->sendResponse($response);
}

function c(){
 ...
 $response = ...;
 return $response // This should not be allowed
}

function sendResponse($response){
  // do something with $response
  return $response;
}

}
```

Comment: How is that helpful? You're the author of your own code, why would you need code-tricks to ensure a certain workflow when you're in the perfect position to adhere to your own api? Also, what will happen when you actually need a method inside the class to call another method and use that return value?

Comment: The background is other team is using my teams classes. My team codes interact with different thirdparty services and all of them return response in different ways. I want to standardize this response for other team so that they know every service they call will have same parameters in response. Its not only me who will write these classes so i have to make this thing mandatory. Its just an idea. If this can be achieved in some good way please share. Thanks

Comment: Why not simply write unit tests for those methods? If the test fails, something is amiss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__call` magic method. If you use this method you must assure that the methods are well documented because other programmers might think that the methods can't be used because they are protected/private.

```
class Foo {

    protected $notAllowedMethods = array('sendResponse');

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (in_array($method, $this->notAllowedMethods)) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException('This method cannot be called directly.');
        }

        $response = call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);

        if (!is_array($response)
            || !isset($response['sendResponseUsed'])
            || !$response['sendResponseUsed']
        ) {
            $response = $this->sendResponse($response);
        }

        return $response['response'];
    }

    protected function a()
    {

       echo 'a' . PHP_EOL;
       return $this->sendResponse('test');
    }

    protected function b()
    {

       echo 'b' . PHP_EOL;
       return $this->sendResponse('test');
    }

    protected function c()
    {

       echo 'c' . PHP_EOL;
       return 'test';
    }

    protected function sendResponse($response)
    {
        echo 'sendResponse' . PHP_EOL;
        // do something with $response
        return array(
            'sendResponseUsed' => true,
            'response' => $response
        );
    }

}

$foo = new Foo;

$foo->a();
$foo->b();
$foo->c();
```

Comment: Isn't it that the __Call only get executed when we try to call a method that doesn't exists or private/protected ?

Comment: You're right @RaheelKhan it was my mistake.. I've updated my answer.. Is just an workaround. Hope it helps

Comment: You solution is a nice work around but unfortunately in my case i am following an interface also so its not possible for me to change visibility of methods :( . May be my requirement is something against the programming paradigm lol